# Google Api Calendar add Attendee

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, gmail-api

i am trying to add an attendee to a existing event using the google calendar api, i am using php, the problem is all existing attendees get an email notification of the updated event, any idea how to send the notification to the new attendee only?

This is possible directly in gmail like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6i2G.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please consider adding your code to the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Patch, instead of update:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch